# istream::tellg() returns -1 when used with my custom streambuf class?

Tags: c++, istream, streambuf

I'm trying to create an `istream` that reads directly from a raw memory buffer.

I found a nice way to do this in another post on here:

```
  class membuf : public basic_streambuf<char>
  {
  public:
      membuf(char* p, size_t n) {
          setg(p, p, p + n);
      }
  };
```

Then I create my `istream` using this `membuf`:

```
    membuf mb(dataPointer, dataLength);
    istream reader(&mb);
```

I then read using `getline()` and `>>` operators, and everything is wonderful. However, I can't seem to use `seekg()` to rewind back to the beginning of my buffer, and `istream::tellg()` always returns `-1`.

Do I need to write some more code to get these to work, or is this doomed to failure?

Comment: Do you _know_ that `seekg()` isn't rewinding? Have you proven that `tellg()` works properly?

Comment: Yes, after calling seekg(0), getline() doesn't read my first line.  The tellg() function definitely doesn't work, as it always returns -1, (even when I just started reading from my buffer).  I believe Bo's answer is the way to go here...

Comment: E@dSanville: OK; I clarified your question accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The functions tellg and seekg depends on protected virtual functions `seekoff` and `seekpos`, that you would have to implement in your `membuf` class.

The defaults in `basic_streambuf` just returns `pos_type(off_type(-1))` for all calls (which might be equal to -1 for many implementaions).

Comment: Thank you very much!  I will implement those right away.  I'm curious though, how does istream::tellg() use those functions?  Does it call streambuf::seekoff(0, ios_base::cur) and get the return value?

Comment: In effect, yes. It actually calls pubseekoff, which then calls seekoff, but that's an interface design detail. :-)

Comment: I am trying to do this... implement `seekoff` & `seekpos` on a custom membuf class, except there's a problem in my code:  `seekoff` is not being called consistently by `tellg` and `seekpos` is not called at all.  Any suggestions or working examples?